# Monogame - Create CheckBox object

Tags: c#, checkbox, monogame

I've been working on a GUI for my game. So far I've used code to create objects that look like "forms" (not to be confused with winforms, I'm using monogame). Also I created buttons. But now I'm having difficulty creating a checkbox. So here is my `CheckBoxGUI` class:

```
// take a look into the recent edits for this post if you need to see my old code.
```

My `TextOutliner` class used to draw text with borders/outlines:

```
// take a look into the recent edits for this post if you need to see my old code.
```

And finally, here's how I use the `CheckBoxGUI` class in my `TitleScreen`:

```
// take a look into the recent edits for this post if you need to see my old code.
```

Here is my problem (at least that's where I think it is, in the method that handles the checkbox logic):

```
// take a look into the recent edits for this post if you need to see my old code.
```

And finally, `Draw()`:

```
// take a look into the recent edits for this post if you need to see my old code.
```

So the method `CheckBoxInputTS` allows me to check/uncheck a CheckBoxGUI item with mouse clicks, but I can't actually attach any functionality to this. For instance I can do the following inside that same method:

```
// take a look into the recent edits for this post if you need to see my old code.
```

Perhaps I'm missing something simple, or I don't understand how to actually make further improvements into the code I already have to make it support different functionalities for the `checkBoxes`... However, when I test this, if I open the window and check the box the window closses and won't open again. The `IsOpen` member of the `WindowGUI` class controls whether the window is visible or not through an if-statement in the class' `Draw()` method.

The same thing happens if I try to use other examples for the checkboxes... Once `checkBox.IsChecked` has a user-given value I can't change it.

If someone can find what I'm doing wrong and help me clean-up this code, it will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Here's what I have so far, based on the proposed answer:

```
public class CheckBoxGUI : GUIElement
{
    Texture2D checkBoxTexEmpty, checkBoxTexSelected;
    public Rectangle CheckBoxTxtRect { get; set; }
    public Rectangle CheckBoxMiddleRect { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public event Action<CheckBoxGUI> CheckedChanged;

    public CheckBoxGUI(Rectangle rectangle, string text, bool isDisabled, ContentManager content)
    : base(rectangle, text, isDisabled, content)
    {
        CheckBoxTxtRect = new Rectangle((Bounds.X + 19), (Bounds.Y - 3), ((int)FontName.MeasureString(Text).X), ((int)FontName.MeasureString(Text).Y));
        CheckBoxMiddleRect = new Rectangle((Bounds.X + 16), Bounds.Y, 4, 16);
        if (checkBoxTexEmpty == null) checkBoxTexEmpty = content.Load<Texture2D>(Game1.CheckBoxPath + @"0") as Texture2D;
        if (checkBoxTexSelected == null) checkBoxTexSelected = content.Load<Texture2D>(Game1.CheckBoxPath + @"1") as Texture2D;
    }

    public void OnCheckedChanged()
    {
        var h = CheckedChanged;
        if (h != null)
            h(this);
    }

    public override void UnloadContent()
    {
        base.UnloadContent();
        if (checkBoxTexEmpty != null) checkBoxTexEmpty = null;
        if (checkBoxTexSelected != null) checkBoxTexSelected = null;
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
        if (!Game1.IsSoundDisabled)
        {
            if ((IsHovered) && (!IsDisabled))
            {
                if (InputManager.IsLeftClicked())
                {
                    ClickSFX.Play();
                    IsHovered = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (IsClicked) OnCheckedChanged();
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        if ((FontName != null) && ((Text != string.Empty) && (Text != null)))
        {
            if (IsChecked) spriteBatch.Draw(checkBoxTexSelected, Bounds, Color.White);
            else if (IsDisabled) spriteBatch.Draw(checkBoxTexEmpty, Bounds, Color.Gray);
            else spriteBatch.Draw(checkBoxTexEmpty, Bounds, Color.Gray);
            TextOutliner.DrawBorderedText(spriteBatch, FontName, Text, CheckBoxTxtRect.X, CheckBoxTxtRect.Y, ForeColor);
        }
    }
}
```

And then the `GUIElement` class:

```
public abstract class GUIElement
{
    protected SpriteFont FontName { get; set; }
    protected string Text { get; set; }
    protected SoundEffect ClickSFX { get; set; }
    public Rectangle Bounds { get; set; }
    public Color ForeColor { get; set; }
    public Color BackColor { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public bool IsHovered { get; set; }
    public bool IsClicked { get; set; }

    public GUIElement(Rectangle newBounds, string newText, bool isDisabled, ContentManager content)
    {
        Bounds = newBounds;
        Text = newText;
        IsDisabled = isDisabled;
        FontName = Game1.GameFontSmall;
        ForeColor = Color.White;
        BackColor = Color.White;
        ClickSFX = content.Load<SoundEffect>(Game1.BGSoundPath + @"1") as SoundEffect;
    }

    public virtual void UnloadContent()
    {
        if (Bounds != Rectangle.Empty) Bounds = Rectangle.Empty;
        if (FontName != null) FontName = null;
        if (Text != string.Empty) Text = string.Empty;
        if (ClickSFX != null) ClickSFX = null;
    }

    public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (!IsDisabled)
        {
            if (Bounds.Contains(InputManager.MouseRect))
            {
                if (InputManager.IsLeftClicked()) IsClicked = true;
                ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                IsHovered = true;
            }
            else if (!Bounds.Contains(InputManager.MouseRect))
            {
                IsHovered = false;
                ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
        else ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

And this is my usage:

```
// Fields
readonly List<GUIElement> elements = new List<GUIElement>();
CheckBoxGUI chk;
bool check = true;
string text;

// LoadContent()
chk = new CheckBoxGUI(new Rectangle(800, 200, 16, 16), "Hide FPS", false, content);
chk.CheckedChanged += cb => check = cb.IsChecked;
elements.Add(chk);

// UnloadContent()
foreach (GUIElement element in elements) element.UnloadContent();

// Update()
for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++) elements[i].Update(gameTime);
foreach (CheckBoxGUI chk in elements) chk.Update(gameTime);

// Draw()
if (chk.IsChecked) check = true;
else check = false;
if (check) text = "True";
else text = "False";
spriteBatch.DrawString(Game1.GameFontLarge, text, new Vector2(800, 400), Color.White);
if (optionsWindow.IsOpen) chk.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

Comment: expose an event and hook to it?

Comment: Sorry, I've never gotten into advanced event-oriented programming. I've used win forms for simple things but I have never had the actual need to work with events, (well, that is until now, of course) aside from the pre-defined ones for winforms so I never learned them...

Comment: Then google a bit for a tutorial on how events work, events will be your next best friend, it will change your ways of seeing things ;)

Comment: Also, if you used forms, all of that are events, a Click, a MouseMove and so on, maybe you know them but didn't knew they were events.

Comment: I'm sure events will help clean up all that `bool` mess in my code... But first I must learn them. @Gusman I know they are events, I just never got into advanced stuff such as creating my own events! I just started making my own GUI objects.

Comment: Please get out of the habit of abbreviating things like `Txt`. You're only saving 1 character and it's not helping the readability of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to what @craftworkgames suggested, you can also pass a delegate through the checkbox constructor, and invoke it directly. The difference between this and events is marginal; an event is basically a list of delegates (i.e. managed pointers to functions), and "firing an event" simply calls all handlers you attached (using `+=`) in succession. Using events will provide a more uniform way (at least more comfortable to .NET developers), but I will also mention some other aspects in my answer.

This is the general idea:

```
public class CheckBoxGUI : GUIElement
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    // instead of using the event, you can use a single delegate
    readonly Action<CheckBoxGUI> OnCheckedChanged;

    public CheckBoxGUI(Action<CheckBoxGUI> onCheckedChanged, Rectangle rectangle)
        : base(rectangle) // we need to pass the rectangle to the base class
    {
        OnCheckedChanged = onCheckedChanged;
    }

    public override bool Update(GameTime gameTime, InputState inputState)
    {
        if (WasClicked(inputState)) // imaginary method
        {
            // if we are here, it means we need to handle the inputState
            IsChecked = !IsChecked;

            // this method will be invoked 
            OnCheckedChanged(this);

            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    ... drawing methods, load/unload content
}
```

When you instantiate the checkbox, you can simply pass an anonymous method which will get called on state change:

```
var checkbox = new CheckBoxGUI(
    // when state is changed, `win.IsOpen` will be set to a new value
    cb => win.IsOpen = cb.IsChecked, 
    new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)
);
```

(btw, the difference between this approach and events is rather negligible:)

```
// if you had a 'CheckedChanged' event, instantiation would look something like this
var checkbox = new CheckBoxGUI(...);
checkbox.CheckedChanged += cb => win.IsOpen = cb.IsChecked;
```

**Create a base gui class with shared functionality**

I would also extract most functionality into a base class. This is the same reason `Control` class exists as the base class in WinForms, and you will be repeating this over and over again unless you use a base class.

If nothing else, all elements have a bounding rectangle and the same way of checking for mouse clicks:

```
public class GUIElement
{
    public Rectangle Bounds { get; set; }

    public GUIElement(Rectangle rect)
    {
        Bounds = rect;
    }

    public virtual bool Update(GameTime game, InputState inputState)
    {
        // if another element already handled this click,
        // no need to bother
        if (inputState.Handled)
            return false;           

        // you should actually check if mouse was both clicked and released 
        // within these bounds, but this is just a demo:
        if (!inputState.Pressed)
            return false;

        // within bounds?
        if (!this.Bounds.Contains(inputState.Position))
            return false;

        // mark as handled: we don't want this event to 
        // propagate further
        inputState.Handled = true;
        return true;
    }

    public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch sb) { }
}
```

When you decide that you want your mouse clicks to be triggered on mouse-up events (like it's usually done), you only have a single place in your code where this change should happen.

Btw. this class should also implement other properties shared between all your UI elements. You don't need to specify their values through the constructor, but you must specify **defaults**. This is similar to what WinForms does:

```
public class GUIElement
{
    public Rectangle Bounds { get; set; }
    public SpriteFont Font { get; set; }
    public Color ForeColor { get; set; }
    public Color BackColor { get; set; }

    // make sure you specify all defaults inside the constructor 
    // (except for Bounds, of course)
}
```

To abstract the mouse/touch/gamepad input, I have used a rather simplistic `InputState` above (you might want to extend it later):

```
public class InputState
{
    // true if this event has already been handled
    public bool Handled;

    // true if mouse is being held down 
    public bool Pressed;

    // mouse position
    public Point Position;
}
```

**Inheriting from the base class**

With this in place, your `CheckBoxGUI` now inherits the goodies from `GUIElement`:

```
// this is the class from above
public class CheckBoxGUI : GUIElement
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    readonly Action<CheckBoxGUI> OnCheckedChanged;

    public CheckBoxGUI(Action<CheckBoxGUI> onCheckedChanged, Rectangle rectangle)
        : base(rectangle) // we need to pass the rectangle to the base class
    {
        OnCheckedChanged = onCheckedChanged;
    }

    // Note that this method returns bool, unlike 'void Update'.
    // Also, intersections should be handled here, not outside.
    public override bool Update(GameTime gameTime, InputState inputState)
    {
        var handled = base.Update(gameTime, inputState);
        if (!handled)
            return false;

        // if we are here, it means we need to handle the inputState
        IsChecked = !IsChecked;
        OnCheckedChanged(this);
        return true;
    }

    ... drawing methods, load/unload content
}
```

**Your game/scene class**

At the beginning of your main Game (or Scene) update method, you only need to create the `InputState` instance and call `HandleInput` for all elements:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    var mouse = Mouse.GetState();
    var inputState = new InputState()
    {
        Pressed = mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed,
        Position = mouse.Position
    };

    foreach (var element in this.Elements)
    {
        element.Update(gameTime, inputState);
    }
}
```

**Event based alternative**

Using the event-based approach, you would change the check box to:

```
// this is the class from above
public class CheckBoxGUI : GUIElement
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public event Action<CheckBoxGUI> CheckedChanged;

    protected virtual void OnCheckedChanged()
    {
        var h = CheckedChanged;
        if (h != null)
            h(this);
    }

    public CheckBoxGUI(Rectangle rectangle)
        : base(rectangle) // we need to pass the rectangle to the base class
    { }

    // the rest of the class remains the same
}
```

And instantiate it:

```
var cb = new CheckBoxGUI(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
cb.CheckedChanged += cb => win.IsOpen = cb.IsChecked;
```

**Update**

This is how your `Update` call stack should look like:

- `Game.Update`

  - calls `TitleScreen.Update`
- `TitleScreen.Update`

  - calls `element.Update` for **gui elements** (not just checkboxes)
- `GuiElement.Update`

  - checks if this element was clicked (to be reused by derived classes)
- `CheckBoxGUI.Update`

  - calls GuiElement.Update (base.Update) to check if just clicked
  - if clicked, changes its state, visual properties and fires the event

If you are doing things right, you should have a list of **gui elements** in your screen class, not actual instances. Screen should not know or care which exact type of the element is being drawn:

```
readonly List<GuiElement> elements = new LIst<GuiElement>();
var chk = new CheckBoxGUI(new Rectangle(800, 200, 16, 16), "Window", false, content);
chk.CheckedChanged += cb => win.IsOpen = cb.IsChecked;

// from now on, your checkbox is just a "gui element" which knows how to
// update itself and draw itself
elements.Add(chk);

// your screen update method
foreach (var e in elements) 
    e.Update(gameTime);

// your screen draw method
foreach (var e in elements) 
    e.Draw(gameTime);
```

Comment: By `Game`/`Scene` class do you mean `Game1.cs`?

Comment: @JohnyP.: yes, most likely. I wrote `Scene` because people often have a "scene manager" of some sort to keep screens organized into different classes.

Comment: Oh, I have this as well, I call it `ScreenManager` :) You were close.
Also, `InputState`. I have my own `InputManager` class which checks for mouse clicks. So far I've been using this code to handle clicks: `if (newMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)` and then making `oldMouseState = newMouseState`. Despite this, it doesn't detect the click when the mouse is up, but when the left button is pressed...

Comment: @JohnyP.: it should be the other way around, current state should be `Released` with previous state `Pressed` to detect a mouse up (pressed -> released). The complete way would actually be to check if within bounds when changed from released to pressed, save this flag, and then fire a click event if you detect a change from pressed to released and still within bounds. The point was only to abstract this info into a simple class, so that you can easily switch to a `TouchPanel` or some other form of input.

Comment: No, I'm only planning to work on a PC project, for now. Also the `bool Update(GameTime gameTime, InputState inputState)` in the `CheckBoxGUI` class has no return value... I'm assuming I must `return true;` right? Also, hat is the `OnCheckedChanged = setter;` part? Edit: oh I can't believe I reversed them! Now it works like a charm!

Comment: Yes, you can return `true`, although now that I think of it, this information is already in the `.Handled` property, I was writing this out of my head. Sorry for the `setter` part, that's was a typo (fixed it). It's just the part where you save the method reference (passed through the ctor parameter) into a field so that you can invoke it later.

Comment: can you take a look at the bottom of my question and see if that's how I'm supposed to have the `Update()` bool?

Comment: @JohnyP.: the actual `Update` implementation I was going for it the one where I inherited from `GUIElement`. I'll fix it at both places. **The point was to return `true` if you handled the click, `false` if you didn't.** For example, if you have a groupbox with several checkboxes, and one of them handles the event, then you don't propagate the event to the groupbox. Otherwise the groupbox receives the click. But the `.Handled` property contains this information anyway, so you can change the method back to `void` as well to remove redundancy.

Comment: I'm about to accept this as an answer, although using this approach I couldn't completely clean-up the `TitleScreen` class and thus, when I click on a `CheckBoxGUI` control, it won't check/uncheck. I will need some assistance to figure out how to do this and making the buttons will be easy! I edited my question with an up-to-date code which I'm currently debugging... Thanks!

Comment: @JohnyP.: take a look at my `GUIElement` class again, all the logic for determining whether the touch intersects an element is there in the `Update` method. You shouldn't set any properties (like `IsHovered` or `ForeColor`) from the screen class, but only iterate through all child elements and call their `Update` methods (the same holds for the `TitleScreen.Draw` method). `GUIElement.Update` should  detect the click for all elements, `CheckBoxGUI.Update` should do additional checkbox-specific actions like changing the color or texture. Start by removing the `CheckBoxInputTS` method.

Comment: Additionally, 1) you should be calling `OnCheckedChanged` within the `CheckBoxGUI.Update` method, and 2) you must attach the event handler only once (i.e the part where you do `checkBox.CheckedChanged += cb => win.IsOpen = cb.IsChecked` should happen right after you create the checkbox, not every time you click on it).

Comment: I updated my code as you said and it still won't check after click? I edited my question with the newest code. It does close the `win` but no check... Even if I open the `win` again, it's not checked.

Comment: @JohnyP.: remove the `CheckBoxInputTS` method, and simply have `foreach (var c in checkboxes) c.Update(gameTime)` (and `foreach (var c in checkboxes) c.Draw(gameTime)` in the draw method). Also, what is `Game1.IsSoundDisabled`? Are you sure you don't want the checkbox to work if sound is disabled? You have changed my code quite a bit. You set `IsHovered` to `true` in `GUIElement`, when `InputManager.IsLeftClicked()` is false. Then in `CheckBox` you expect `IsHovered` to be true, **and** `InputManager.IsLeftClicked()` to be `true`. Set a breakpoint inside the `Update` method and examine it.

Comment: And of course, `OnCheckedChanged()` has to be called when `IsChecked` changes, not in every `Update` cycle. It's hard for me to make suggestions since this code is completely different from my answer, I am just repeating what I wrote above. **I updated the end of the answer with some remarks.**

Comment: I have updated my code once again. The current behavior of the program: I open `optionsWindow`, click on `chk` and the window closes, without the checkBox being checked. Then I can't open the window anymore. I can't seem to find a way of using this event... So frustrating...
Edit: I will try to think of another example for this checkBox that doesn't involve the window to be closed. I'll try to figure this out.

Comment: Alright, now I'm sure it's the event. I did `chk.IsChecked = true;` and it was properly showing the checked checkBox. When I clicked on it, it didn't uncheck. I wonder what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Remove the `checkBoxes` array, you only need a list of elements.

Comment: I wrote an attempt to see if the checkBox ever changes to checked/unchecked (edited question). If checked => `check = true`, else its false and then used that with `SpirteBatch.DrawString` to see the result. I clicked on the checkbox, it didn't check, `False` did not change to `True`... It must be the event. I can't comprehend what's wrong with it :(

Comment: If your code still looks like posted above, it won't work unless you remove the `checkBoxes` array. Right now you're calling `Update` twice for each check box, once through the `elements` list, and then through the array. So, even if it gets checked, it will immediately be unchecked. Of course, there could be more errors, but that's why I wrote you should stick to the code I wrote.

Comment: `checkBoxes` has been removed. I tried commenting out `e.Update(gameTime);` or `chk.Update(gameTime);` (so I can call `Update()` only once), but the same thing as I posted above still happens.

Comment: I think I found the problem. It's the `OnCheckedChanged()` method. If I put a breakpoint on the `chk` initialization, when the program starts, it gets hit and I read `h = null`. Is this normal? Should that be the normal behavior?

Comment: Anyway, I read some articles online and figured it out. Thanks for taking the time to help me with the endeavor of making a GUI for my game!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the main thing you're struggling with is figuring out how to implement events. So I'll go over that with a really simple example.

Imagine we want to implement a simple `Click` event. First create an event member on your class like this:

```
public event EventHandler Click;
```

Then in your `Update` method you need to raise that event in much the same way you are playing a sound effect.

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (!Game1.IsSoundDisabled)
    {
        if ((IsHovered) && (!IsDisabled))
            if (InputManager.Instance.IsLeftClicked())
            {
                clickSFX.Play();
                IsHovered = false;

                if(Click != null)
                    Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
    }
}
```

That's pretty much all there is to it. You can now sign up to that event in other parts of your code. For example:

```
checkBox.Click += CheckBox_Click;
```

And implement the event just as you would in WinForms.

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // do something when the check box is clicked.
}
```

There's not a lot else you need to know about events to get started. The only thing I would say is that if thread safety is a concern you should get into a habit of raising your events like this:

```
var eventHandler = Click;

if(eventHandler != null)
    eventHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

But that's a story for another time.

There's plenty of other things about your code that could use some improvement but I think that's out of the scope of this question. If you want to get more feedback on your code I suggest posting it on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: While this answer sure is easier to implement, it is based on my flawed (WET) GUI code structure so it will get harder and harder to maintain... I will have to re-do pretty much all of my `GUIElements` with the purpose of adding a single `abstract class` to hold their mutual properties and make my life easier.

Comment: Yes, you could definitely use some code refactoring but I can't solve all the problems in a single answer. Writing a GUI is hard.

Comment: I definitely agree that writing a GUI is hard, hence this question. I'll try to figure some things out myself too.

Comment: Hey @craftworkgames! I tried your solution as well. Although it worked, it was not registering the clicks every time I clicked. Any ideas why?

Comment: More than likely there's something wrong with the logic in your update method or something related to the variables used in it. For a start I can see that clicks don't fire if the sound is disabled. That's probably no this bug though. Use breakpoints to see what's going on the those 2 nested if statements.

Comment: No, I actually re-organized the if-statement so that it plays the soundeffect if sound is enabled and fires the event regardless of the sound. As I said I've been using this to detect clicks:
`if (newMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)` and then `oldMouseState = newMouseState` so it can't be a problem with click logic, can it?

Comment: I'll do it myself and will report the results in a comment.

Comment: Strangely enough, `IsChecked` is always `true` even though I wrote this in `CheckBox_Click`: `checkBoxes[0].IsChecked = !checkBoxes[0].IsChecked;

MainGame.IsFPSEnabled = !MainGame.IsFPSEnabled;`

Comment: Hmmm that sounds weird @JohnyP. where did you put the `event` call?

Comment: Actually I had that in `Update()`... Now that you mentioned it I moved it to `LoadContent()` and it was fixed! I knew there was some delay between the times the event was called but I didn't know it was because I called it in `Update()`. That fixed it for me.